# Vim: yank highlighted text

Tags: vim

I have a pattern highlighted and I want to copy all the text highlighted and paste it into another buffer. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

`y`

Then change to your other buffer, and

`p`

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong. When I do the above, the entire line get yanked and i want to copy only the highlighted text.

Comment: @Nahuel: Make sure you use a lower-case `y` to yank the text. An upper-case `Y` will yank the entire line. That's if you used `v` or the mouse to highlight the text. If you searched for that text using a pattern, you can yank the matched text with `y//e`.

Comment: @garyjohn Yes I'm doing a pattern search and then working with the results. This time I did yank the highlighted with `y//e` but only the first match. Can i yank all the words matched at the same time and then paste them, for example, at the end of the file?

Comment: @Nahuel: I can't think of an easy way to do that. You could append each match to the `a` register, for example, by prefixing the yank with `"A`, but you'd have to type `"Ay//e` at each match. The only way I can think of to yank all the matches with one command would be to write a script.

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking for but I will typically use the global commands for this...
Basically do :v/pattern/d that will get rid of all non matching lines... then I will yank the remaining lines into the new buffer and undo my previous command... Usually at that point the results are closer to what I want and fairly easy to manipulate further to get the desired results.  Hope this helps.